# How to define a parametric type alias

Tags: scala, type-safety

I try to define a parametric type alias :

```
case class A
case class B
case class C

// We need an Int to load instances of A and B, and a String to load C
object Service {
  def loadA(i: Int) : A = ???
  def loadB(i: Int) : B = ???
  def loadC(s: String) : C = ???
}

trait Location[T] { def get : T}
class IntLocation(val i: Int)
class StringLocation(val s: String)

trait EntityLocation[E] extends Location[_]

// Aim : make the loader typesafe
// Problem : I need something like that : type EntityLocation[Composite] = IntLocation
object Family {
  trait EntityLoader[EntityT] extends (EntityLocation[EntityT] => EntityT)
  val ALoader = new EntityLoader[A] {def load[A](l: EntityLocation[A]) = Service.loadA(l.get)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Could you please explain how you want to use these types in your code?
Assuming just want to use the types `IdLocation` and `FileLocation` in your code, maybe you want to try

```
trait Location[T] { def get : T }
type IdLocation = Location[Id]
type FileLocation = Location[java.io.File]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems rather convoluted, so I'm not sure I follow exactly what your purpose here is. You seem to go into many layers of factories that create factories, that call factory methods, etc.

Seems to me that at the end of the day you need you want to have a `val ALoader` value that you can use to get instances of A from Location[Int] objects, so I'll go with that assumption:

```
     // Not sure what you want this one, but let's assume that you need a wrapper class per your example.
     trait Location[P] { def get: P }
     class IntLocation(val i: Int) extends Location[Int]
     {
        override def get: Int = i
     }

     // P for parameter, O for output class.
     def loader[O, P](creator: P => O)(param: Location[P]) = { creator(param.get) }

     object Service
     {
        // A function somewhere, capable of taking your parameter and creating something else (in your example, an Int to an 'A')
        // here Int to String to make something concrete.
        // This could be any function, anywhere
        def loadA(someParam: Int) = someParam.toString
     }

     def main(args: Array[String])
     {
        val myStringLoader: Location[Int] => String = loader(Service.loadA)
        // Alternatively, you could have written `val myStringLoader = loader(Service.loadA)(_)`. Either the type or the underscore are needed to tell the compiler that you expect a function, not a value.

        // Some definition for you wrapper class
        val location3 = new Location[Int]{
           override def get: Int = 3
        }

        // ... or just a plain old instance of it.
        val otherLocation = new IntLocation(5)

        // This would 'load' the kind of thing you want using the method you specified.
        val myString = myStringLoader(location3)
        val myOtherString = myStringLoader(otherLocation)

        // This prints "3 - 5"
        print(myString + " - " + myOtherString)
     }
```

This might seem like a long answer, but in truth the line `def loader[O, P](creator: P => O)(param: Location[P]) = { creator(param.get) }` is the one that does it all, the rest is to make it as similar to your sample as possible and to provide a working main you can use to start from.

Of course, this would be even simpler if you don't really need the Location wrapper for your integer.

Comment: For a given class O, P is fixed and I want to make that appears in the type system.

Comment: Could you explain further? I tried to solve what your example showed, but I'm afraid maybe I don't quite understand what you are trying to accomplish. How would it look like "if it worked"?

Comment: For the record: O and P can be anything, and the type system will indeed be aware and validate all types involved.